# Haar feature calculation with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction

Hi,

I try to evaluate some Haar feature (and then LPB and HOG feature) using opencv in order to use them in Adaboost later. For that, I am using the [FeatureEvaluator](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#featureevaluator) from OpenCV.
But I got an exception when I try to calculate one feature. Here is how I am doing:

```
Ptr<FeatureEvaluator> ptrHaar = FeatureEvaluator::create(FeatureEvaluator::HAAR);

Mat img = imread(image_path); // image of size 2048*1536 correctly loaded
ptrHaar->setImage(img, Size(100, 100));
ptrHaar->setWindow(Point(0, 0));
double res = ptrHaar->calcOrd(0); // get the exception here
```

And i receive this message:

Unhandled exception at 0x6CA471D8 (opencv_objdetect248d.dll) in MLtraining.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCE0D.

So I am wondering what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

FeatureEvaluator should not be used when you have not trained your classifier.

You can use trained sample (like haarcascade_eye.xml in data\haarcascades) to trace codes.

The steps are

```
CascadeClassifier ptrHaar;
ptrHaar.load("haarcascade_eye.xml");
ptrHaar.setImage(img, Size(100, 100));
ptrHaar.setWindow(Point(0, 0));
```

and you will find the ptrHaar has a vector of features which indices are stored in the haarcascade_eye.xml.